# how to call web service from blackberry native application

Tags: java, web-services, blackberry

This is my code in Blackberry java Eclipse plugin How can i invoke webservice in this code to store the below mentioned fields like _firstName ,_lastName ,address,mobileNumber in database by calling web service from this code.
please say about database and how can i set up the database in blackberry application as specific to call the webservice in the blackberry application,ie in my ui design i have firstname,lastname,mobilenumebr and address i have to store this fields in database by calling the webservice,pls give me some idea or codes for webservices and setting up database as specific to blackberry application. Thanks in advance

```
  package mypackage;
    import net.rim.device.api.database.Database;
    import net.rim.device.api.database.DatabaseFactory;
    import net.rim.device.api.database.Statement;
    import net.rim.device.api.io.URI;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.DrawStyle;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.FieldChangeListener;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.BasicEditField;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.DateField;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.RadioButtonField;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.RadioButtonGroup;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.RichTextField;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.SeparatorField;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.HorizontalFieldManager;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager;

    public final class CreateProfileScreen extends MainScreen {
        Database d;
        BasicEditField _firstName = new BasicEditField("First Name:", "");

        BasicEditField _lastName = new BasicEditField("Last Name:", "");

        BasicEditField mobileNumber = new BasicEditField("MobileNumber:", "");

        BasicEditField address = new BasicEditField("Address:", "");


        public CreateProfileScreen() {
            HorizontalFieldManager btns = new HorizontalFieldManager(
                    HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER);

            ButtonField save = new ButtonField("Save", ButtonField.FIELD_HCENTER);
            // adding these objects to the Blackberry Application.
            VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(
                    VerticalFieldManager.FIELD_LEFT);
            vfm.add(_firstName);

            vfm.add(new SeparatorField());

            vfm.add(_lastName);
            vfm.add(new SeparatorField());
            vfm.add(mobileNumber);
            vfm.add(new SeparatorField());
            RadioButtonGroup rbg = new RadioButtonGroup();
            vfm.add(new RadioButtonField("Male", rbg, true));
            vfm.add(new RadioButtonField("Female", rbg, false));
            vfm.add(new SeparatorField());

            vfm.add(new DateField("DOB:", System.currentTimeMillis(),
                    DateField.DATE | DrawStyle.LEFT));
            vfm.add(new SeparatorField());
            vfm.add(address);
            vfm.add(new SeparatorField());
            vfm.add(save);

            add(vfm);

            FieldChangeListener btnlistener = new FieldChangeListener() {

                public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
                    // Open a new screen

                    String fname = _firstName.getText();
                    String lname = _lastName.getText();
                    String mobno = mobileNumber.getText();
                    String addr = address.getText();

                    if (fname.length() == 0 || lname.length() == 0)
                        Dialog.alert("firstname and lastname is mandatory!");
                    LabelField title = new LabelField("SQLite Insert Data "
                            + "Schema Sample", LabelField.ELLIPSIS
                            | LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
                    setTitle(title);
                    add(new RichTextField("Attempting to insert data into "
                            + "MyTestDatabase.db on the SDCard."));
                    try {
                        URI myURI = URI.create("D:///db/" + "MyTestDatabase2.db");
                        d = DatabaseFactory.open(myURI);

                        Statement st = d
                                .createStatement("INSERT INTO People(Name,Age) "
                                        + "VALUES ('John',37)");
                        st.prepare();
                        st.execute();
                        st.close();
                        d.close();
                        add(new RichTextField("inserting data successful"));
                        System.out.println("inserting data successful");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            };
            save.setChangeListener(btnlistener);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
try {

        String httpURL="www.your url.com/register?fname="+fname_value+"&lname="+lname_value+"&mobno ="+no_value+"&addr="+address_value;
        HttpConnection httpConn;
        httpConn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(httpURL);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
        DataOutputStream _outStream = new DataOutputStream(httpConn.openDataOutputStream());
        byte[] request_body = httpURL.getBytes();
        for (int i = 0; i < request_body.length; i++) {
            _outStream.writeByte(request_body[i]);
        }
        DataInputStream _inputStream = new DataInputStream(
        httpConn.openInputStream());
        StringBuffer _responseMessage = new StringBuffer();
        int ch;
        while ((ch = _inputStream.read()) != -1) {
            _responseMessage.append((char) ch);
        }
        String res = (_responseMessage.toString());
        String responce = res.trim();

        Dialog.alert(responce);

        httpConn.close();


    }catch (Exception e) {
        Dialog.alert("Error");
    }
```